# Showing that $f (x) = 3 \cdot e ^ {- 0,397x}$ with integration?

Tags: calculus, integration

**I have been given this figure and the following information:**

[image: Figure]

> The colored area of the curves between point A, B and C in the figure
> shows the cross section of a roof surface. In relation to the
> coordinate system entered in the figure, the following is known:
>
> - The colored area is symmetrical about the y-axis
> - Point B has the y-coordinate 3
> - Point A has the x-coordinate 5
> - The curve between point B and A follows the graph of the function:
>   $f (x) = a \cdot e ^{kx}$ where a and k are constants
> - The tangent to this curve at point B has the angle $130 ^ o$ with the x-axis
> - The angle between the tangent to the same curve at point A and the x-axis is $180 ^ o-v$

With that I have to solve the following problems. The thing is I have no idea how to solve them using integration. I have looked everywhere in my notes and searched on the internet but without any luck. I am mostly asking for help on a), but I figured that I should post the other problems as well in case I don't know how to solve them either.

> a) Show that $f (x) = 3 \cdot e ^ {- 0,397x}$ (with 3 decimal places
> on the determination of k)
>
> b) Determine the height h in the cross section
>
> c) Determine the angle v
>
> d) Calculate the area of the colored area

All help is **greatly** appreciated because I simply have no clue on what to do.

Comment: You don't need integration until part (d). Until then it's just solving equations using the given information.

Comment: Just to be clear, does that mean I can't use integration until part d) or does it mean that it is possible but I don't need to do integrate? 
I'm asking since the problems I am given by my teacher usually has to be solved using the methods we're currently learning.

Comment: I don't see any meaningful way to _use_ integration in (a), (b) or (c).